# SQL Server using row_number and partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the following we are getting the list via these conditions.

customers of us with latest payment date is grower then the entered date and with only selected payment types ( cash, cheq, credit card etc)

Dear Gordon Linof previously help me for using `Row_number` section and query works.

But today we have a strange situation. Query doesnt get a customer in list wand when we have a look we find that that customer did not send a payment to us. so the query doesnt find the last payment record and because of this doesnt shown on the list.

Now the problem ... How can i change this query for if a customer doesnt do a payment before.

```
SELECT t.cari_kod 
       AS Cari_Kod, 
       t.cari_unvan1 
       AS Unvan, 
mikrodb_v14_dekor2011.dbo.Fn_carihesapanadovizbakiye('', 0, t.cari_kod, '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0) AS BakiyeTutar,
t.cari_temsilci_kodu 
       AS TmsKodu, 
cpt.cari_per_adi 
       AS Adi, 
cpt.cari_per_soyadi 
       AS Soyadi, 
t.cha_tarihi 
       AS Tarih, 
t.cha_meblag 
       AS Tutar, 
Datediff(day, t.cha_tarihi, Getdate()) 
       AS GunFarki, 
t.cari_bolge_kodu 
       AS Bolge 
FROM   (SELECT cr.*, 
               chh.*, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY chh.cha_kod 
                   ORDER BY chh.cha_recno DESC) AS seqnum 
        FROM   mikrodb_v14_dekor2011.dbo.cari_hesaplar cr 
               LEFT JOIN mikrodb_v14_dekor2011.dbo.cari_hesap_hareketleri chh 
                      ON chh.cha_kod = cr.cari_kod 
        WHERE  1 = 1 
               AND chh.cha_tip = 1 
               --and chh.cha_cinsi in (0,1,2,3,4,5,19,20)   
               AND chh.cha_evrak_tip IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                          34, 65, 67, 98 ) 
               AND chh.cha_tarihi > '20130101') t 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN mikrodb_v14_dekor2011.dbo.cari_personel_tanimlari cpt 
                    ON ( t.cari_temsilci_kodu = cpt.cari_per_kod ) 
WHERE  t.seqnum = 1 
       AND t.cari_temsilci_kodu IN ( 'PKAD01', 'PKMS04' ) 
ORDER  BY 
mikrodb_v14_dekor2011.dbo.Fn_carihesapanadovizbakiye('', 0, cari_kod, '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0) DESC
```

Comment: your query is hard to understand, but understanding your problem description just try to take the entered date if last payment date is null. Functions are available in sql for this.

Comment: Ray the manager want to see them both together. i dont know maybe  should use union all to combine with the new version which allow the nuuls like you proposed.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/285e673d-2f3d-4618-8349-f08eb40f6a21/assign-empty-string-if-datetime-is-null